# How do I apply Solr 'More Like This' component as part of my search

Tags: solr

I'm trying to perform a solr query that includes 'More Like This' component. Can't find this scenario in the documentation. Here's a hypothetical sample Product entity with two fields -

```
{
   product_name: "name of the product in 3 or 4 words"
   product_description: "this is a long english verbose text, may be 10 
   sentences"    
}
```

If I'm given a newProduct, I want to search for similar products in my Solr Index. The search should use the following logic -

- newProduct.product_name - I want to do a simple token based search against 'product_name' field in my index.
- newProduct.product_description - I want to use this field to perform 'More Like This' search against 'product_description' field in my index.

How can this be accomplished with a single query to Solr?

Let me know if the scenario is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the More Like This request handler (mlt) to perform a "More Like Search" with a given document text without adding the document to the index first.

Include the document as the POST data or in the `stream.body` parameter in the request. There's an [example given in the old wiki](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/MoreLikeThisHandler#Using_ContentStreams) - see "Using content streams":

> If you post text in the body, that will be used for similarity. Alternatively, you can put the posted content in the URL using something like:
>
> http://localhost:8983/solr/mlt?stream.body=electronics%20memory&mlt.fl=manu,cat&mlt.interestingTerms=list&mlt.mintf=0
>
> If remoteStreaming is enabled, you can find documents similar to the text on a webpage:
>
> http://localhost:8983/solr/mlt?stream.url=http://lucene.apache.org/solr/&mlt.fl=manu,cat&mlt.interestingTerms=list&mlt.mintf=0

Comment: I've seen this in the docs, but what I'm trying to accomplish is a little different. I don't want to perform a separate query to retrieve 'more like this' hits. I would like it to be part of my main query that has other search criteria along with an mlt field.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's possible unless the document is already indexed

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:
https://wiki.apache.org/solr/MoreLikeThis#MoreLikeThisComponent

It uses the MoreLikeThis Component in search rather than having a separate handler.